# Tweak output from an arraylist

Tags: java, oop, printing, arraylist

This is my last requirement that I need to fulfill and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I am attempting to display only the ContactID, the first name, and last name of the contacts entered into the array. 
I have a function in my parent class that is set to display the ContactID, First Name, and Last Name. 
My issue is it does output these details. But it outputs the full details of the last entered contact before it prints the Contact.

This is my main class: Option 3 is where the issue is.

import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int type = 0;
    while(type != 5){
    System.out.println("Please select an option: ");
    System.out.println("Add a Personal Contact: Enter 1 ");
    System.out.println("Add a Business Contact: Enter 2 ");
    System.out.println("Display Contacts List: Enter 3 ");
    System.out.println("Display Contact Details: Enter 4 ");
    System.out.println("To Quit: Enter 5 ");

    type = input1.nextInt();

    if(type == 5){
        System.out.println("Goodbye ");
        break;
    }
```

if (type==1 || type==2){

```
     Contact contact = null;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter ContactId : ");
    String contactId = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter First Name : ");
    String firstName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Last Name : ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Address : ");
    String address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Phone Number : ");
    String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Email Address : ");
    String emailAddress = input.nextLine();

    //Create a personal contact.
    if(type == 1){
       System.out.println("Please enter Birthday: ");
       String dateofBirth = input.nextLine();
       Contact pcontact = new PersonalContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, dateofBirth);
       contacts.add(pcontact);
    }
    //Create a business contact.
    else if(type == 2){
        System.out.println("Please enter Job Title: ");
        String jobTitle = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Organization: ");
        String organization = input.nextLine();
        Contact bcontact = new BusinessContact(contactId, firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber, emailAddress, jobTitle, organization);
        contacts.add(bcontact);
    }

}
    //Print full name of each Contact.
    if(type == 3){
        System.out.println(contacts);
        for (Contact namecontact: contacts)
        {
            System.out.println(namecontact.displayFullName());}
    } 
    //Print contact details for selected contact.
    else if(type == 4){
            System.out.println("Enter a Contact ID to display Contact Details: ");
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String soughtID;
            soughtID = input2.nextLine();
        for (Contact showcontact1: contacts)
            {
               if (showcontact1.displayId().equals(soughtID))
                System.out.println(showcontact1.displayContact());
            }
        }
     }
}
```

}

Here is the Parent class that holds the method: displayFullName is what I am calling.

package ooo1;

public abstract class Contact {

```
String contactId;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String address;
String phoneNumber;
String emailAddress;

public Contact(String contactId,String firstName,String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress)
{
    this.contactId = contactId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}
public void setContactId(String input){
    this.contactId = input;
}
public String getContactId(){
    return contactId;
}

public void setFirstName(String input){
    this.firstName = input;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String input){
    this.lastName = input;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setAddress(String input){
    this.address = input;
}
public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String input){
    this.phoneNumber = input;
}
public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String input){
    this.emailAddress = input;
}
public String getEmailAddress(){
    return emailAddress;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
   return ("ContactID: " + this.getContactId() + "\nFirst Name: " + this.getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + this.getLastName() + "\nAddress: " + this.getAddress() + "\nPhone Number: " + this.getPhoneNumber() + "\nEmail Address " + this.getEmailAddress());
}

public String displayFullName(){
    System.out.println("Contact: ");
    return ("ContactID: " + this.getContactId() + "\nFirst Name: " + this.getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + this.getLastName());
}

public String displayContact(){
    return ("ContactID: " + this.getContactId() + "\nFirst Name: " + this.getFirstName() + "\nLast Name: " + this.getLastName() + "\nAddress :" + this.getAddress() + "\nPhone Number :" + this.getPhoneNumber() + "\nEmail Address " + this.getEmailAddress());
}
public String displayId(){
    return (this.getContactId());
}
```

}

This is what the output looks like:

3
[ContactID: 3
First Name: Tom
Last Name: Jones
Address: 123 West St.
Phone Number: 345-235-2345
Email Address: tjones@yahoo.com
Date of Birth: 12-12-1978]
**Contact: 
ContactID: 3
First Name: Tom
Last Name: Jones**

I just want from Contact: (in bold above) when I call this.

How do I get it to stop showing the full details for the last contact entered.

Comment: Dnt found any issue in the code to print all the detail.Have u use toString method

Comment: I can print all details fine the problem is I can not get it to print just the Contact ID, First Name, Last Name that I am trying to call from displayFullName().  It wants to print out the last contact I entered when I call option 3 then it will print displayFullName after it. Like there needs to be away to clear what it has before it prints my next call.

Comment: OP, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below line,becoz it is printing the contact object.

```
    if(type == 3){
        System.out.println(contacts);   // Remove this line
        for (Contact namecontact: contacts)
        {
            System.out.println(namecontact.displayFullName());
        }
```

Comment: @user3196742 plz check and let me knw